# Is the Location header allowed to have a vertical bar?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers

I recently came across a server that's sending a Location header (for a redirect) that looks like this:

```
Location: http://www.example.com/something.ext?auth=123|123
```

When I try to use this in my Java program it complains about an "Illegal character in query" and fails.

So is the server doing something incorrect? Is this legal?

Comment: @AdamBernier Don't think so: I'm specifically asking about the Location header.

Comment: @yddl Even though the URL is located in the Location header, it still must follow the definition of a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use escapes:

- http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

`|` is escaped with `%7C`, so your URL becomes:

```
Location: http://www.example.com/something.ext?auth=123%7C123
```

`Location` header as per [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) is defined as:

```
Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
```

Per [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2):

> For definitive information on URL syntax and semantics, see "Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax and Semantics," RFC 2396

RFC 2396 is obsoleted by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which requires escaping of some characters (see the RFC for the definitive information). It's the responsibility of the source to provide the correct URL, so yes - you are responsible to provide a correctly escaped URL in this case.

Comment: So are you saying it's the responsibility of the client (i.e. me) to do this escaping?

Comment: That's correct - see my edit for a bit more information. Basically, as a source, you need to provide the correct URL.

Comment: Well to be clear I'm not the server. I just happened to have come across a server that exhibits this behavior. So to be clear: you're saying that I'm not the one doing anything incorrect, and that the server should be giving me an escaped url, right?

Comment: Yes - whoever is **sending** the URI should be responsible for escaping it. In this case, you are the **receiver** from the server that is giving you wrong URIs. In this case, you'll probably have to use (or write if there's none) some pre-processor that will convert these for your application.